# Add a shell script to xcode project and double click to run it

Tags: xcode, shell

I added a shell script file to Xcode project and gave extension as .command

My intention is to double click it to run my script. But when i double click it opens in text editor.

How to make it execute without leaving Xcode IDE? Please advise.

Comment: Did you add it as a Run Script build phase?

Comment: I don't require this to be part of build phase. It's device/simulator configurator. Idea is to run once when switching between the environment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible to run directly by double-clicking in the Project Navigator in Xcode; but you could create a new Aggregate target and assign your script to a Run Script build phase in that target.  It would just require switching back and forth between targets.